# how to limit number of entity. google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to make just 1 DailyPost entity. But when I make two requests at the same time, there are two DailyPost entities.

How can I limit this?

Environment:

Google App Engine

runtime : Python27

datastore : ndb

```
def get_today():
  return datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time())

class DailyPost(ndb.Model):
  user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
  content = ndb.StringProperty()
  created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class GetOrCreateHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    user = session.get_user() # user from session (pseudo code)
    post = DailyPost.query(DailyPost.created >= get_today(), 
                           DailyPost.user==user.key).get()
    if not post:
      # Delay to test. (or time.sleep)
      for i in range(30000):
        print 1
      post = DailyPost(content='some text..', user=user.key)
      post.put()

    self.response.write(post.content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use unique value of each day as a key with [get_or_insert](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert) method:

```
import datetime

class DailyPost(ndb.Model):
  user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
  content = ndb.StringProperty()
  #created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class GetOrCreateHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    user = self.session.get_user() # user from session (pseudo code)
    _id = '%s.%s' % (user.id, datetime.date.today().strftime('%s'))
    DailyPost.get_or_insert(_id, user=user, content='bla')
    self.response.write(post.content)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need a post for each user. `DailyPost.query(DailyPost.created >= get_today(), 
                           DailyPost.user==user.key).get()`

Comment: Just put user ID in the key before timestamp. Please look on updated answer.

Comment: I think I should use ndb.transactional with ancestor query. Anyway thanks.

Comment: If you have your own solution for this problem please answer this question by yourself and accept this answer, so question will be closed.